# QGIS: Transposing rows of each month for each point into columns

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a very large table that I would like to transpose into QGIS with the ultimate goal of adding this method into a graphical modeler.

I have a table like below. This screenshot shows only one `idpoint` but my table has hundreds of similar points.

[image]

I would like this table with the `month` rows as columns combined with the columns `prtotAdjust`, `tasAdjust`, `rsdsAdjust` and `rldsAdjust`. I would like to have only one row per `idpoint`. The column `field_1` is not important and can be removed.

What method should I use to integrate this easily into a graphic modeler?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more: you expect to have 12x4 columns like `prtotAdjust1`, ...,`prtotAdjust12` etc ? Can you also explain a bit more what is the overall datapipeline and why you want the reformatting to be part of the graphic modeler ? As a virtual layer running the relevant query can be used to generate an always up-to-date table with the format you expect, I am wondering if it would not be simpler than having a graphic modeler function need to be run.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Kasper.
Yes I expect to have 12*4 columns. I am working on a climate change modeling project. The goal is to build a graphical modeler that can be shared with other entities so that they can reproduce the method effortlessly from data cleaning to the modeling result. So the table will not be updated in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the graphical modeler `Execute SQL` function:

[image]

[image]

I have run it on a small sample data:

[image]

Use this as an SQL query template:

```sql
select id, max(rtot1) as rtot1, max(rtot2) as rtot2, ...other fields...,  max(rtot12) as rtot12 from
(select id,
case when mois=1 then rtot end as rtot1 ,
case when mois=2 then rtot end as rtot2 ,
case when mois=3 then rtot end as rtot3 ,
case when mois=4 then rtot end as rtot4 ,
case when mois=5 then rtot end as rtot5 ,
case when mois=6 then rtot end as rtot6 ,
case when mois=7 then rtot end as rtot7 ,
case when mois=8 then rtot end as rtot8 ,
case when mois=9 then rtot end as rtot9 ,
case when mois=10 then rtot end as rtot10 ,
case when mois=11 then rtot end as rtot11 ,
case when mois=12 then rtot end as rtot12 
--- add more rows for the other 3 parameters/12 months

 from 'Input') group by id
```

---

If you want the query to handle the geometry from your input layer:

- make sure that when importing th CSV, LambertX & LambertY are taken as X & Y coordinates,
- use the following query:

```sql
select geometry,id, max(rtot1) as rtot1, max(rtot2) as rtot2, max(rtot12) as rtot12 from
(select geometry,id,
case when mois=1 then rtot end as rtot1 ,
case when mois=2 then rtot end as rtot2 ,
case when mois=3 then rtot end as rtot3 ,
case when mois=4 then rtot end as rtot4 ,
case when mois=5 then rtot end as rtot5 ,
case when mois=6 then rtot end as rtot6 ,
case when mois=7 then rtot end as rtot7 ,
case when mois=8 then rtot end as rtot8 ,
case when mois=9 then rtot end as rtot9 ,
case when mois=10 then rtot end as rtot10 ,
case when mois=11 then rtot end as rtot11 ,
case when mois=12 then rtot end as rtot12 

 from Input) group by id,geometry
```

You will see that the Output layer now natively has geometries:

[image]