# Converting X, Y coordinates as one geometry field

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-modeler

In a QGIS graphic modeler I use the `Execute SQL` algorithm with as input a CSV with point features like the image below.

[image]

`LambertX` and `LambertY` contain the x and y coordinates.
In the SQL query I added following.

```
select idPoint, .....other fields....., LambertY, LambertY from ...
```

When running my model I get the error:

```
raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("Cannot find geometry field"))
```

I also tried to use `geom_from_wkt('POINT( LambertX  LambertY)')` as expression under `Geometric field` of the Execute SQL algorithm (see image below) but I get the same error.

[image]

What would prevent this error?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not adding the CSV as a delimited text layer and setting the geometry directly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIwKp.png

Comment: I added the CSV to my project like you said @user2856 but when running the model the problem still occurs.

Comment: Please provide details on why you feel the need to access a column instead of the original geometry.

Comment: First the fields name should be between quote in your expression, second 'POINT( LambertX  LambertY)' wont return a valid WKT string for the geom_from_wkt() to evaluate...

Comment: Based on the comment of @Kasper, I have edited my question for clarification

Comment: try geom_from_wkt('POINT ( ' || "LambertX" || ' ' || "LambertY)" || ')') as expression for your geometry

Comment: @J.R Using geom_from_wkt('POINT ( ' || "LambertX" || ' ' || "LambertY)" || ')') I get the same error again

Comment: @GisUser: I have updated the Answer to your other [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452520/qgis-transposing-rows-of-each-month-for-each-point-into-columns), to show how you can handle geometry field natively from the SQL request, without having to "manually" generate a geometry field from LambertX/Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the input of @Kasper I managed to make it work by adding geometry in my SQL request:

```
select geometry, idPoint, .....other fields....
from
...csv.... 
group by idPoint, geometry
```

No input is needed under `Geometric field`.